USB HID Consumer Volume Increment/Decrement as relative input auto-repeats on Win10
I have implemented a rotary encoder to control a Host PC's volume through as an HID device. Here's the report descriptor:
0x05, 0x0C, /* Usage Page (Consumer). */
0x09, 0x01, /* Usage (Consumer Control). */
0xA1, 0x01, /* Collection (Application). */
0x85, 0x03,   /* Report ID (3). */
0x05, 0x0C,   /* Usage Page (Consumer). */
0x95, 0x02,   /* Report Count (2). */
0x75, 0x01,   /* Report Size (1). */
0x15, 0x00,   /* Logical Minimum (0). */
0x25, 0x01,   /* Logical Maximum (1). */
0x09, 0xE9,   /* USAGE (Volume Increment). */
0x09, 0xEa,   /* USAGE (Volume Decrement). */
0x81, 0x26,   /* Input (Data,Var,Rel,No Wrap,Linear,No Preferred State,No Null Position). */
0xC0,       /* End Collection. */

On Linux, it works perfectly.
On windows 10, it has a very odd, variable behavior depending on the action:

If I rotate the knob several ticks, it works perfectly.
If I rotate the knob a single tick in the same direction as the last tick, it works perfectly.
If I rotate the knob a single tick in the opposite direction than the last tick, Windows happily auto-repeats the command until the volume is 0% or 100%. Why?

I specified that the data is Relative, has No Preferred State and has No Null Position. Why is Win10 auto-repeating the action in that specific case when my device has stopped sending reports?
Edit (Nov. 28th 11:14): Just to clarify, if the device systematically sends a NULL report after each non-null report, it solves the problem. Though the question remains, why is Windows auto-repeating an input clearly configured as a non-repeating type.

Volume Increment and Decrement are defined in HID Usage Tables as Retrigger Control, specified to "trigger a repeating event as long as it is asserted" (3.4.1.5). So if you send a report with one of the two bits set, Windows seems to correctly implement this behavior. As you noted, you need to send a null report to clear the repetition.
Side note, having defined them as relative seems suspicious to me. They should be absolute, they are meant to reflect the state of a momentary button.
Lastly, if you actually have a rotary knob, you'd rather declare a signed item reflecting the rotation amount from the knob as Volume (Consumer page, 0xE0, defined as Linear Control) where you can actually use a relative item.
This could be close to the example A.2 from the spec with a Volume item rather than Tape Jog. Something like:
 0x05, 0x0c,                    // UsagePage (consumer)
 0x09, 0x01,                    // Usage (ConsumerControl)
 0xa1, 0x01,                    // Collection (Application)
 0x15, 0x81,                    //     LogicalMinimum (-127)
 0x25, 0x7f,                    //     LogicalMaximum (127)
 0x75, 0x08,                    //     ReportSize (8)
 0x95, 0x01,                    //     ReportCount (1)
 0x09, 0xe0,                    //     Usage (Volume)
 0x81, 0x06,                    //     Input (Variable|Relative)
 0xc0,                          // EndCollection

This would allow reflecting the rotational speed as accurate volume modifications.

It seems odd that all those configuration parameters can be tweaked. You seem to suggest that whatever the USB HID Table puts forward is the only valid configuration. Then why explicitly define all those settings if the Usage itself should carry all the required information? I would've thought it was built with flexibility in mind.
